# What is the best way to convert a List[Short] to Array[Byte] in Scala?

Tags: scala, type-conversion, arrays, short

This is very straightforward in C/C++, but I am wondering what is the most elegant way in Scala? Thanks!

Comment: `shorts.flatMap(s => List((s >> 8).toByte, s.toByte)).toArray`

Answer (score 2):

Consider bit operations such as shifting and masking to extract the upper and lower bytes of a Scala/Java `Short` (in a very similar fashion as in C/C++); let

```
val xs = (253 to 257).map(_.toShort).toList
xs: List[Short] = List(253, 254, 255, 256, 257)
```

and so

```
def upper(x: Short) = ((x >> 8) & 0xFF).toByte
upper: (x: Short)Byte

def lower(x: Short) =  (x & 0xFF).toByte
lower: (x: Short)Byte

xs.map( x => (upper(x), lower(x)) ).toArray
res2: Array[(Byte, Byte)] = List((0,-3), (0,-2), (0,-1), (1,0), (1,1))
```

where each tuple collects the upper and lower bytes of each `Short` value. 
One approach to flattening the array of tuples above,

```
xs.flatMap( x => Array(upper(x), lower(x)) ).toArray
res3: Array[Byte] = Array(0, -3, 0, -2, 0, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy to do in Scala, in fact, you can almost literally translate the English sentence in your question into code. Assuming you have a `List[Short]` called `l`:

```
l.map(_.toByte).toArray
```

Obviously, you need to make sure that all your `Short`s in the list actually fit into a `Byte`, otherwise you will get truncated results.